# R data.entry is not working on OS X El Capitan

Tags: r, macos, x11

When I use R language, I can't use data entry:

```
$ R
> cheese = c(1,2,3)
> data.entry(cheese)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: can't open file: /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources/modules/R_de.so (No such file or directory)
Error in dataentry(odata, as.list(Modes)) : X11 is not available
In addition: Warning message:
running command ''/usr/bin/otool' -L '/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources/modules/R_de.so'' had status 1
```

But I installed X11, XQuartz 2.7.7.

Comment: Does this file exist?  /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources/modules/R_de.so

Comment: No I don't. I installed the R by using Homebrew. Another laptop using same procedure didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need X11 support in order to use this function. Reinstall R with:

```
brew reinstall r --with-x11
```

It should then work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Installing 'R' from RStudio helped me in fixing this problem. I had installed 'R' using brew, therefore first uninstalled 'R' using command-

Atuls-MacBook-Pro:~ atulkaushik$ brew uninstall r

Then downloaded the appropriate package 'R-x.y.z.pkg' from [RStudio](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/). Though, this step helped me in running x11() on terminal, I was still not able to perform operations using this function.

> m=matrix(1:81,9,9)
>   data.entry(m)
>   Error in .External2(C_dataentry, data, modes) : 
>     unable to start data editor
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In dataentry(odata, as.list(Modes)) :
>     locale not supported by Xlib: some X ops will operate in C locale
>   2: In dataentry(odata, as.list(Modes)) : X cannot set locale modifiers
>   3: In dataentry(odata, as.list(Modes)) :
>     unable to create fontset -*-fixed-medium-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-*-*

instead of invoking r shell through command 'r', I used LC_CTYPE=C R command

Atuls-MacBook-Pro:~ atulkaushik$ LC_CTYPE=C R

Now, when I execute

> data.entry(m)

System will open a XQuartz window like -

[image: Data Editor XQuartz Window]